# Can't Login using GUI

Tags: login, lightdm

I can't login to my standard or guest session using the Ubuntu GUI.I think its a problem of the greeter because I can login to my standard account in console mode.However there is no problem in login using an administrator account.

Comment: The kernel is in /boot. See: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1328502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complaining on this site did'nt help at all other than being pointed for 'law breaking' and getting answers for questions that were removed by the moderator from the moderator hinmself(Now thats what we call irony.).Anyway I found a solution to my problem.
As I doubted it was the problem of the unity.I could open my account using openbox.After that I only had to reinstall ubutnu-desktop for the problem to be solved.
One thing the world of linux(And the reason why I am using it even when all else in my state uses windows.) has teached me is that you are always your best teacher here.

Comment: Your answer would be much improved if you included the process you used to reinstall ubuntu-desktop so that others might have the benefit of your experience. Asking for help is always more effective than complaining IMHO.